# Dead or stuck pixel during booting

Tags: display, dead-pixel, stuck-pixel

Greetings to all the experts,currently i'm facing a problem on my monitor,it can't show anything during booting,this bugged me as i can't look into BIOS setting,this is the video i've captured.

part 1  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnjkIe3QZYY

part 2   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSWMZ3jyc4A

I really need help in fixing this problem,thanks for spending time reading my question

***I'm using an analog VGA monitor*

Comment: I noticed you selected cd/dvd for the boot device? What DVD are you booting from? Does it do this for all boot devices?

Comment: Windows installation CD , i can't see anything when it is loading vital file for the installation to be carry out,but not after it shows the blue GUI screen where windows started to install.For windows 7 installation CD,because it is fully GUI,that is why my monitor could display it

Comment: Did you try a different boot CD/DVD, or another W7 DVD? Maybe its defective

Comment: It's not the CD/DVD problem,i can tell you is if i don't boot any cd too it'll be like that during booting,can't even show the boot setting screen,even if i change to other pc on this monitor,it is still the same

Comment: Check the user manual for that monitor, see if it has a factory reset method.

Comment: What graphics card are you using? Are you using a DVI/VGA adapter? Have you tried removing/refitting the graphics card and leads?

Answer (score 0):

It's doubtful that the monitor is your problem as it works once the OS is loaded and the PC should only direct low res graphics to it before the drivers are loaded. Therefore, I think you should be looking at the graphics card. Edit your original post with answers to my questions in the comments above. There are some test programmes available which could help depending on your hardware.